# Bash 4.4.0 causes nano to fail with Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian, socat

The problem is very specific, but I figured out the conditions for failure:

system is: `Linux` 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP `Debian` 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) i686 GNU/Linux

when i do the following set of commands:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x18,nonblock tcp:192.168.1.111:23
nano somefile
```

Everything works, when I replace `bash` binary 4.3.30 with compiled 4.4.0, `nano` fails with error message:

```
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

Which will not go away unless I start another instance of `bash`. This problem exist also on `Ubuntu` and `Kali` that have `bash` 4.4.0 natively. I tried running `socat` in a subshell, in a script, perform `stty sane` after it, change the escape character and many other things, but to no avail. Removing `nonblock` or using older version of `bash`, however, fixes the problem (but I depend on bug fixes in 4.4 and on `nonblock` switch). I believe this a bug in `bash` and I would like to see if the hive mind has any suggestion (other than reporting the bug).